# NSCalendar in Swift - init can return nil, but isn't optional

Tags: swift, nscalendar

`NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: calendarName)` can return `nil` if `calendarName` is not valid - this is the original Objective-C behaviour, and is also true in Swift. However, it appears that the compiler believes the initializer returns an `NSCalendar` rather than an `NSCalendar?`, as follows:

```
let c1 = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "gregorian")// _NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper
let c2 = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "buddhist")// _NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper

//let c3:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "rubbish") // run-time error
let c3:NSCalendar? = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "rubbish") // nil
```

So if the initializer can return nil, my understanding is that I should be able to do

```
if let c4 = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "rubbish") as? NSCalendar { 
    //error: conditional downcast from 'NSCalendar' to 'NSCalendar' always succeeds
}
```

However, this is a compile-time error as shown.

What am I misunderstanding here, and how can I safely test that a named calendar actually exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** The following only applies to Swift 1.0. In Swift 1.1, there are failable initializers.

---

This works:

```
if let c4 = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "rubbish") as NSCalendar? { 

}
```

In Swift 1.0, there is a known issue in the Xcode release notes about Swift not supporting Objective-C initializers that return `nil`. Basically, what is happening is that according to the Swift language, the expression `NSCalendar(...)` has type `NSCalendar`, which is a non-optional type (cannot be `nil`). However, this is really an imported initializer from Objective-C, where it can return `nil`.

So what currently happens is that when you call this and it returns `nil`, you have a value that at runtime is `nil`, but Swift thinks is a non-optional `NSCalendar` (which cannot be `nil`). This is a really bad situation in which you have a value that is not possible for the type. The Xcode release notes mention a "workaround" where you convert the result of the initializer to an optional type before using it. The reason that this works is that at runtime, both optional and non-optional object pointers are represented as simple pointers, where `nil` object pointer is the null pointer, and non-optional ones are assumed to not be null pointers. The operation of converting from a non-optional to optional object pointer is a simple assignment (in both cases it's a non-null pointer). But in the case where the value is `nil`, a simple assignment turns it into a (valid) `nil` value of optional type. So everything is happy.

But if you don't convert it to optional first, all hell breaks loose, as you have a value that is not supposed to be possible for that type.

Your attempt to downcast using `as?` from `NSCalendar` to `NSCalendar` isn't allowed, because a cast from `NSCalendar` to `NSCalendar` cannot fail (theoretically).

Comment: So, the `?` was misplaced.

Comment: this is no longer true with Swift 1.1 introducing Failable initialisers

Answer (score 2):

Even though it looks like the initialiser should return a full NSCalendar object, it appears as though it behaves as an implicit optional (NSCalandar!).  If you look at the object in the debugger it comes up as an NSCalendar:

(NSCalendar) $R1 = 0x0000000000000000 { ObjectiveC.NSObject = parent is NULL }

Even more strange is that the following code does not produce any runtime errors, when accessing a nil NSCalendar - at least for me:

```
    let x = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "asdasda")
    let y = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    if (x.isDateInToday(NSDate())) {
        println("x works")
    }

    if (y.isDateInToday(NSDate())) {
        println("y works")
    }
    if (x == nil) {
        println("x not calendar")
    }

    if (y == nil) {
        println("y not calendar")
    }
```

For me this outputs 'y works' and 'x is not a calendar'.  This would in pure Swift have a runtime error if using a nil implicit optional but pqnet points out that calling a method on a nil pointer in objective c doesn't produce an error, it is just ignored - which is what seems to be doing.  So strange, but it does appear in this case safe to do this:

```
    let x = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "asdasda")
    if (x != nil) {
        //do what you need with the calendar
    }
```

However a more Swift way would be to use an explicit optional - i.e. do this:

```
    let x : NSCalendar? = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "asdasda")
    if let cal = x {
        //do what you need with the calendar as cal
    }
```

You could also use an implicit optional `let x : NSCalendar =...` and check with `if x != nil` as above - your choice, it seems sometimes different contexts cause implicit or explicit optionals...

Edit:

From the [Xcode release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_6_gl2i5q/xcode_6__beta_6_release_notes.pdf):

Swift does not support object initializers that fail by returning null. (16480364)!
Workaround: If there is a factory method, use it instead. Otherwise, capture the result in an optional. For example:

```
let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: "not a url")
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that breaking out the assignment and the test is a kludge that gets round it, but what type would you make `x` if you were explicitly typing it - `NSCalendar?` works, but `NSCalendar` will produce a run time error...

Comment: objective-c method are supposed to be safe if called on `nil`, that is, they simply don't have any effect and if a value is expected on return, that value is going to be zero, so do not expect a crash or runtime error if using `nil` calendar

Comment: Grimxn it would be your choice, probably best to use NSCalendar?, but NSCalendar! could also work and you can still test for nil.  pqnet, true I forgot that, thanks.  I will update the answer to reflect both these comments.

Comment: @james_alvarez thanks for your efforts and insights on this, but I'm going to leave it open for now because I don't think we've got to the bottom of it!

Comment: Yes it is a mystery as to why you can create a non-optional NSCalendar, and when nil have it behave like objective C, ignoring method calls, however this wasn't the original question!  It would make a really good other question though...