# Physics Body unwrapping causes fatal error while using Sprite Scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skscene

I've working on a simple platform game and everything worked well until I tried to use a SpriteKit Scene for the playing screen.

I have a menu screen, originally I would click on start game and it would start the scene with the default GameScene(size: size). This works well and I have no errors, but the new code I want doesn't work with this.

In order to make my code work, I tried changing it to GameScene(fileNamed: "GamePlay") and thus call a SpriteKit Scene; the game runs well until I click on start game and it crashes with the following message:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The line where this appears it's just after I declare the size of the physics body of a SKNode: ground.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

I've searched and I've done the tests for nil value and I know it has nil value, but I don't know how to replace it and it only occurs when I add the SpriteKit Scene. I've also read that it might have to do with having three or more collisions being detected at the same time, but again, it worked without the Scene.

The SpriteKit Scene in question has only a camera and a sprite, all the other assets are added by code. I also wonder if this is part of the problem?

I add the code I use to call the scene and where the error happens and hope someone can help me or guide me on how to solve this.

MainMenu Class code

```
if nodes(at: location)[0].name == "StartButton" {
            let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GamePlay")
            scene?.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(scene!, transition: SKTransition.doorsCloseVertical(withDuration: 1))}
```

GameScene Class, addGround method

```
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width:self.frame.width, height: self.frame.midY/1.5))

    ground.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    suelo.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.0

    ground.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.EspacioTubos
    ground.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.EspacioTubos
    ground.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.EspacioTubos
```

**EDIT**

Thank you for your comments, just as you asked I changed the size values  of the physic body to fixed values and it worked.

Comment: Can you please try creating the physics body with a fixed size first? I suspect you use zero sized rectangle.

let body = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width:100, height: 100))

ground.physicsBody = body

Comment: I did this and it doesn't crash anymore!! Although now I have problems with the physic body and collisions, but I think I can solve them. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit out there, but could you be calling the `addGround` function before the scene has the size set? (In other words it has `CGSize.zero`)?

I believe that would give the SKPhysicsBody initialiser something to chew on...

Answer (score 0):

Your SKPhysicsBody may not be created if the size is 0 (I tried and it failed! Don't ask me why because the corresponding init is not declared as failable, but fails!), then accessing it through non conditional dereferencing is wrong. Prefer use of optional chaining : `ground.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false`.

---- EDIT ----

Looks like `SKPhysicssBody` is imported from Objective-C which can fail without reporting it in Swift through the typing... Same situation described [here for NSCalendar failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284182/nscalendar-in-swift-init-can-return-nil-but-isnt-optional)